# Multipart/form-data with iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

Following my code:

```
var formElement = document.getElementById("myFormElement");
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", "submitform.php");
oReq.send(new FormData(formElement));
```

The form has two fields, the first is the input field (# I_F), the second a text field (# S_T). How to get the same result with an iframe?

Comment: What do you mean by same result ?

Comment: I want to send it to the server with iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the form target to iframe and it will work

```
<form action="iframe.php" target="my-iframe" method="post">

<label for="text">Some text:</label>
<input type="text" name="text" id="text">
 <input type="submit" value="post">

</form>

<iframe name="my-iframe" src="iframe.php"></iframe> take a look here
```

Comment: Please can you make an example?

Comment: Ok, thanks in advance. But I would ask one thing and then I'll disappear, how can I do this (use iframe to send data to the server) with javascript?

Comment: Connect the form submit with js